# Docker NO_PROXY settings for docker login

Tags: docker

I want to use my own Docker registry. The problem is that we have an http corporate proxy. I use the proxy for the official Docker registry from the Docker hub and it works, but I don't want to use the proxy for my own registry. With curl and --noproxy registry.mydomain.com I get an unauthorized error. Without --noproxy I get the error 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: Looks like you need to provide credentials to your corporate proxy.

Comment: thanks no the problem was that in the configuration file for the docker proxy configuration were semicolon(;) . But if you type in the command systemctl for showing environment all environments are listed but not used. @Adrian W